# Graph API access when logging in as a guest to external tenant (B2B)

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm working through the UWP exercise [in this sample application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-windows-uwp#register-your-application) and have it working. I've tweaked it a bit because the application I'm developing is registered in a directory other than the one my AAD account belongs to (I'm a guest in the directory). I've made the following change:

```
PublicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
                                                .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, TenantId)
                                                .Build();
```

where TenantId is the identifier of the directory where the application is registered and where I'm a guest, rather than my home directory.

The call to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` which is included in the tutorial works fine and returns my profile information to the UWP app.

I'd like to pull my profile photo into the app, so I changed the graph api url to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value`, but this returned an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "NoPermissionsInAccessToken",
    "message": "The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx",
      "date": "2019-05-16T17:15:28"
    }
  }
}
```

The application registration has `User.Read`, `User.ReadBasic.All`, and `openid` for the graph api.

When I use the [graph api explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) to hit the `/me/photo/$value` url it works without issue.

My guess is that my problem is caused by authenticating against a non-authoritative directory which provides a token with limited access to the graph api. I've not been able to find any documentation on the restrictions placed on graph api access for B2B/guest accounts.

My thought is that if I want to do this I'd have to establish a second login session with my home directory (and possibly a second app registration) and use the token from that session to access my profile, but I'm looking for suggestions on how to solve this problem without asking the user log in twice. A solution using MSAL would be ideal.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the error you're receiving it looks like your issue may be related to permissions and not actually the fact that it's a guest. If it were because you were a guest, you should receive a different error.

Can you decode the access token you have? You can do this by getting a decrypted fiddler trace by following this article below : 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/09/12/capture-https-traffic-with-http-fiddler/

And then decode the bearer header for the get call to the Microsoft photo endpoint.

If you do in fact have the right permissions and have met all the requirements in the documentation listed here : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0

I would suggest filing an Azure support ticket to get a support engineer from Microsoft to look into this issue further.

Thanks,
- Frank